# How to add comboBox inside gridData with actioscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I searched for adding comobBox inside gridData ,i found tutorial use mxml ,but i use Flash pro ,so is it possible to do it in code ,or with the Flash interface.

Comment: I know it's possible to do programmatically (in AS3) but I'm not sure about using the GUI to do it with any sort of wizards/drag and drop.  I believe you need to look into making a custom CellRenderer then setting your datagrid to use that cell renderer (though I am mostly a Flex guy myself)

Comment: shaunhusain is right, simply subclass [fl.controls.listClasses.CellRender](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/listClasses/CellRenderer.html) (or implement ICellRenderer) and add a ComboBox instance to that (using composition) class.